# iPhone Obj C -- Sorting a Mutable Array of dictionaries -- display a string but sort by value

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, sorting, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

I have a NSMutableArray with 30 dictionaries inside of it.  Each contains a name and a value. I currently have the names sorted so that the show in a table view alphabetically. However, I'd like to make a UIButton to give the option of STILL DISPLAYING THE NAMES, but ordered by the value. The value doesn't need to be displayed. Also, where in the .m/.h files would these codes be placed? THANKS!

Answer (score 22):

To be able to help you I need a test data to work with. Let's say your array with data looks like this:

```
NSMutableArray *aMutableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
         [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
          @"A", @"name",
          [NSNumber numberWithInt:6], @"value", nil],
         [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
          @"C", @"name",
          [NSNumber numberWithInt:2], @"value", nil],
         [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
          @"B", @"name",
          [NSNumber numberWithInt:4], @"value", nil], nil];
```

In this case case here's how you sort it by value:

```
NSSortDescriptor *aSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"value" ascending:YES];
[aMutableArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:aSortDescriptor]];
```

As for where to place this code place it wherever you need the reordering to happen (in the implementation [.m] file of course).

HTH and if there will be any questions ask them in the comments.

Comment: Thank you very much! However, my array and dictionaries are stored inside a plist!!! Sorry for leaving that out. I've discovered (so it seems) that this would be extremely difficult if not impossible to accomplish. I've therefore moved onto a window-based project, with a tab bar and navigation controllers inside. I am now setting up the first tab, with a nav controller inside of it, which looks like this:

Comment: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
 
 DescriptionViewController *descriptionViewController = [[DescriptionViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DescriptionViewController" bundle:nil];
 descriptionViewController.teamarray = [self.teams
          objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:descriptionViewController animated:YES];
 [descriptionViewController release];

Comment: However, I get the error: Object cannot be set - either readonly property or no setter found. I know it must be easy to solve, but I'm a total newbie at this... Thanks.