# How to sort array of dictionaries

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsdictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I sort an NSArray containing NSDictionaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361207/how-can-i-sort-an-nsarray-containing-nsdictionaries)

I have an array of dictionaries.. This is what my dictionary looks like

```
MOD = 0;
MAU= 30;
MODN = "SOME WORD";
MODID = 518;
```

I have tried sorting the array of dictionaries like this

```
sortedArray = [[ICArray valueForKey:@"MODN"] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

However this only gives me an array of the values in MODN in alphabetical order... where in actual fact I am hoping to get the each dictionary sorted into an array.

Any help would be greatly appreciated..

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8483172/ios-sort-array-with-dictionaries and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149069/iphone-obj-c-sorting-a-mutable-array-of-dictionaries-display-a-string-but

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, I dont think the second version is a very good solution for what I am tying to achieve.. The first one is good but just trying to get it to work for my solution now....

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom block based comparator to look at the values in each of the dictionaries, and sort however you want. Something like below should work for you

```
NSArray *unsortedArray = @[@{@"MOD" : @(0), @"MAU" : @(30), @"MODN" : @"SOME WORD", @"MODID" : @(518)},
                           @{@"MOD" : @(0), @"MAU" : @(30), @"MODN" : @"ANOTHER WORD", @"MODID" : @(518)},
                           @{@"MOD" : @(0), @"MAU" : @(30), @"MODN" : @"THIRD WORD", @"MODID" : @(518)}];

NSArray *sortedArray = [unsortedArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
  return [[obj1 valueForKey:@"MODN"] localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:[obj2 valueForKey:@"MODN"]];
}];
```